# Responsive Bootstrap Design

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make responsive card design.

[Bootstrap Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91ZPM.png)

[I want the cards to appear on the phones in a single row and one below the other.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucDX4.png)

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Az0A.png)

Should I try css @media queries? I am actually trying to learning flexbox so if you can tell me with flexbox it would be good for me i guess. I tried some css codes but didn't work.Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html translate="no">
<head>
  <title>asdas</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="still.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
           <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
            <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">2 Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-100 d-none d-sm-block d-md-none"><!-- wrap every 2 on sm--></div>

    </div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div class="col">
            <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">3 Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
     <div class="w-100 d-none d-md-block d-lg-none"><!-- wrap every 3 on md--></div>
        <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">4 Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing all your `<div class="col">` for `<div class="col-md-6">`!

[Bootstrap 4 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns)